# unknown type name '__priority_which_t'

Tags: c, linux

I just upgraded to fedora 18 with gcc 4.7.2. Code that previously compiled now fails with an error about __priority_which_t

```
unknown type name '__priority_which_t'
int setpriority(__priority_which_t which, 
                id_t who, 
                int prio) __attribute__((weak));
```

I'm guessing the since it's a _t and starts with two underscores it's something provided by the c library or the compiler. Does anyone know where it might have gone or what should now be used in its place?

Comment: A quick google search shows that it's supposed to be in `resource.h` along with the definition of `setpriority`. Link: http://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.17/resource_2sys_2resource_8h_source.html  Can you show some more context?

Comment: Ha! A quick include of <sys/resource.h> did the trick. Carl, what was the query you used to find that, it completely eluded me, I'll accept it if you write it up as an answer.

Comment: I don't know about Carl, but I just Googled `"__priority_which_t"` and found [this page](http://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.17/resource_2sys_2resource_8h.html)...

Comment: Yup, there it is. Huh. I suspect they cleaned up incidental includes in later glibcs and that's what caused the problem to show up now.

Comment: @nneonneo, that's exactly what I did.

Comment: @CarlNorum, Paul: Why doesn't one of you post this as answer?

Comment: OP didn't really provide enough information to know if that *was* the answer.  If Paul wants to put his fix and accept it, that' probably the best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to some cleanup in the header files by the gcc team definitions and types that were previously being incidentally included no longer are. In this case a header which previously indirectly included `<sys/resource.h>` stopped doing so in 4.7.2, breaking the compile.

Directly including

```
#include <sys/resource.h>
```

gets the definition of __priority_which_t and allows the compilation to complete.